# Simplest HTML includer for using in npm script?

Tags: html, import, npm

I need a simple npm script to have includes in my html file to make it modular, it shouldn't be a gulp/grunt/webpack plugin, just a regular npm-lib, like node-sass or whatever.

I tried to use nunjucks/twig/html-importer - they all haven't any watch options, so if you know what I'm seeking - sharing would be appreciated!

UPD: or maybe if anyone has any ideas how to watch nunjucks templates and run build on changes - I will be happy to see your solution as a line of npm-script. nunjucks-cli doesn't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, I've found a solution.

I still used nunjucks-cli, but I used to play with paths, and looks like they were required to be written in quotes, instead of example's version, so script `"nunjucks -w -u '*.tpl' -o ./"` works fine